# How to activate the RabbitVCS plugin for GEdit?

Tags: 14.04, gedit, rabbitvcs

I have installed [RabbitVCS](http://rabbitvcs.org/) and its various extension on system with Ubuntu 14.04:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep rabbitvcs
ii  nemo-rabbitvcs                                        2.8.0-1~webupd8~trusty                              all          Nemo extension for RabbitVCS
ii  rabbitvcs-cli                                         0.16-1~trusty                                       all          Command line interface for RabbitVCS
ii  rabbitvcs-core                                        0.16-1~trusty                                       all          Easy version control
ii  rabbitvcs-gedit                                       0.16-1~trusty                                       all          Gedit extension for RabbitVCS
ii  rabbitvcs-nautilus3                                   0.16-1~trusty                                       all          Nautilus 3 extension for RabbitVCS
ii  rabbitvcs-thunar                                      0.16-1~trusty                                       all          Thunar extension for RabbitVCS
```

However, the RabbitVCS extension is not showing up in the GEdit plugins dialogue:

[image]

I have restarted GEdit but the plugin is still not visible. What should I do to get it working?

Comment: How did you install it? By the PPA in the link you gave?

Comment: I actually installed it from the the official Ubuntu repository. I added the RabbitVCS PPA and upgraded these packages, but the GEdit plugin is still nowhere to be found.

Comment: I was thinking it could be the PPA version is not supported by your gedit version? I installed it with `sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-gedit` and it shows fine in the plug ins list, I don't really know what to suggest if you have tried using the repo version, I was going to suggest not using a PPA.